# How change Actionbar title by switching between Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I have an application with two fragments when the application starts the Actionbar title is the one of the first fragment. But when I'm going to the second Fragment the title doesn't change.

So how do I change the ActionBar title?

This is my code:

```
public class ClientList extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        String title;
        title = getResources().getString(R.string.client_title);
        ActionBarActivity action = ((EmployeeActivity)getActivity());
        action.getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        String title2;
        title2 = getResources().getString(R.string.action_settings);
        ActionBarActivity action = ((EmployeeActivity)getActivity());
        action.getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title2);

    }
}
```

Comment: `getActivity().setTitle(title)`? And you should put your `onDestroyView()` logic before `super.onDestroyView()`, the destroy sequence should be reverse of the create sequence. Also I think you should change the new title in the new fragment, not when current fragment is being destroyed, which may not happen if you simply hide or put it in back stack.

Comment: do you want to change it two times or what? have you tried to change it in `onCreateView` when fragment is just created?

Comment: @Yurets I want to change the title everytime I switch between the fragments. I have tried onCreateView but than I get a unreachable statement error

Answer (score 1):

so if you say you cannot reach the method from `onCreateView`, so this is your solution I think:

```
@Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
                  ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {         
          View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment,
                          container, false);
          getActivity().setTitle("Title"); 
          return view;
  }
```

Because if you `return` before you call `setTitle()` you cannot reach it, that's true.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can set your action bar title inside onCreate(if activity)/onCreateView(if fragment) method as `getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Your Title");`

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
getActivity().setTitle(YOUR_TITLE);
```

Call it from your Fragment when you wanted to set.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you switch from one fragment to another fragment you can set the title in ActionBar. This can be done on onCreateView(...) of a fragment. Advisable try to change the name in Activity in which you are trying to load the fragment.
To do so ....

If you are using appcompat library

`ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setTitle(" your title ");`

If you are not using appcompat library

`ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setTitle(" your title ")`;